# How to parallelize a plain for loop using the C++ standard library

Tags: c++, for-loop, parallel-processing

I feel kind of dumb having to ask this, but I just can't find a non-convoluted way to do this.

I have the following loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
  if (myFunc(i))
    continue;

  myOtherFunc(i);
}
```

Parallelizing this with OpenMP is trivial: Just add `#pragma omp parallel for` before the loop.

I wanted to compare the performance of OMP (and its different schedules) to MSVC's parallel `<algorithms>` implementation (i.e. using C++17 execution policies). The straightforward idea would be to use `std::for_each`, but I can't figure out a good way to transform this super plain `for` loop into any appropriate `<algorithm>` thing that I can throw an execution policy at.

Notably, you can't just do

```
std::for_each(std::execution::par, 0, count, [](int i){ /*...*/ });
```

because you must supply *iterators* (i.e. something that yields the `i` argument when *dereferenced*).

- I could `std::iota` into a `std::vector` of `int` just so I have a range of indices to iterate over. That would be absurd though.
- I could use [`std::generate_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) with some dummy output iterator that discards whatever it is assigned. Since I don't think that's available in `std` I would have to write the full dummy iterator myself. And this would of course be a stupid hack regardless. And getting a hold of the correct index would probably require manual tracking with a `std::atomic<int>` because you don't get to know your current index.
- I really don't have a container to loop over. I mean, somewhere deep inside those functions there are containers, but restructuring everything just so I can use iterators over *some* container in this loop is out of the question.
- 15 minutes of googling different descriptions of this didn't get me anywhere.

**Is there some way to match the most plain and basic `for` loop with `<algorithm>` tools that doesn't involve silly nonsense?**

Comment: You could create your own, simple iterator. It won't need much functionality. And then use for_each

Comment: The `STL` doesn't really deal with arbitrary looping. It gives you *whole algorithms* which do their (potentially parallel) looping internally.

Comment: @Fureeish I've so far tried to stay clear of adhering to the ever-evolving requirements of all kinds of [iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) that the standard library defines. Feel free to add an answer that shows a complete implementation of such a simple iterator though, it's probably the best solution indeed.

Comment: That's why I so much prefer OpenMP. Parallelization is still very immature in C++. Parallelization of a loop is a very basic building block. Another example are missing task pools (OpenMP tasks).

Comment: I wrote a function to break a numerical range into `n` sub-ranges to make hand crafted parallelizing easier. Also one to return a bunch of `gsl::span` type objects for a *container* to make parallel processing over it easier.

Comment: `boost::range` have tools for this concept I believe - but is that (also) out of the question ?

Comment: @darune Boost is not an option for me personally, but that shouldn't stop you from adding an answer (I doubt I'm the only one in such needs). On a related note, I'll remove the "no ranges" part so that an answer for it can be added for that.

Comment: An "integer iterator" really needs four things: Be able to be constructed with a specific value (e.g. `IntIterator(0)`); Implement the increment operator `++`; Be comparable with not-equal with another "integer operator"; And be dereferencable with the unary `*` operator to give the current value. Such an iterator should be possible to implement in less than ten lines (including filler such as curly-braces, and with both prefix and suffix `++`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Conceptually yes, but isn't there a whole lot of extra boilerplate to make stuff work with `iterator_traits` and such? Again, I'm unsure about this because just about every major C++ version changes things up and I haven't bothered to keep up. Should be a short answer to write if it's indeed that trivial.

Comment: While iterator traits are good to have, it's really just extra fluff for such a simple case. :)

Comment: Are [execution policies](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) what you are looking for? For instance, using a parallel execution policy on `std::for_each()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, indeed. The question is what range you use to operate on. Let me clarify the question.

Comment: I think maybe the problem is that `<algorithm>` tools only deal with containers and iterators and not arbitrary indexes that are not even necessarily related to containers. You say you want to compare timing between `OpenMP` and `std::for_each` but `std::for_each` requires a *container* and *iterators* whereas your eample code does not. So the question as a whole is somewhat confusing tbh.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well, MSVC yells at me about not finding the appropriate specialization of `iterator_traits` if I implement just the constructors and operators `==`, `!=`, `*`, `->` and both versions of `++`. It appears you do have to do the whole song and dance...

Comment: Ah well, it didn't needed to be implemented last I created an iterator. But that might depend on what it's used for? It should not be hard to solve though, according to [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) all you need are five type-aliases (or six, for C++20).

Answer (score 3):

If using [boost](/questions/tagged/boost), you may use the `boost::irange` (in [boost-range](/questions/tagged/boost-range)) to produce the counting loop like this:

```
auto ints = boost::irange(0, count);
std::for_each_n(POLICY, ints.begin(), boost::size(ints), [](int i)
{
  if (!myFunc(i)) {
    myOtherFunc(i);
  }
}
);
```

Comment: Nice! I assume this doesn't actually create `count` integers in memory for `ints` but just provides the iterators?

Comment: I suppose that the `continue` has no longer any meaning in your lambda. You should rewrite to something like `if(!myFunc(i)) myOtherFunc(i);`.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I am not really sure about that (it support random access). But there is also one called boost::counting_range https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/counting_range.html

Comment: It seems to not be the case:             reference dereference() const
            {
                return m_first + (m_step * m_step_size);
            }